# ADF Copy Pipeline not reading/writing all rows

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I have a simple copy pipeline that reads from a CSV file and writes to a Azure SQL database.  The pipeline finishes with no errors. On inspection, however, I can see that only 107,506 of the 129,601 rows are actually being read/written. The giveaway that this was not working is that the last row written to the table was not written completely.

The format of the file looks to be intact and formatted correctly. What is causing this issue (timeout issue?), and what options do I have to detect this in the future?

**** EDIT
It appears the issue is further up my pipeline. I am using a Logic App to check for new CSV files on an FTP site and then copy these files to Azure Blob Storage. On two occasions, the write of the logic app has cut off the file at 10 MB. This appears to be new as prior to 5/1 I was often exceeding 10MB. Is this in Azure change?

Comment: Are the writes happening sequentially? And you've checked the CSV in a simple text editor, like Notepad++, to ensure there are no formatting or syntax issues?

Comment: The writes are sequential and checked the csv as you mention and nothing looks strange. No formatting issues, extra carriage returns or line feeds.

Comment: Could you provide a line that gets inserted and one that doesn't?

Comment: I've noticed on a subsequent file, different data, it has again stopped at exactly 107,506 rows.  Is there something that limits row inserts somewhere in ADF?

Answer (score 0):

Check settings in copy activity . I suspect `skip incompatible rows` is selected in `Fault tolerance` option.